# How to implement URL rewrite in classic ASP using custom 404 page?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

My web host told me that they are using Windows IIS (not sure about the version) and are unable to implement a URL rewrite for me. I am now looking at alternative ways to do this. Obviously, I don't have access to the IIS server. I read somewhere that using a custom 404 page, I am able to implement a URL rewrite from my end using classic ASP.

I want to do a URL rewrite for subdomain.mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com/subdomain.

I am a bit lost about the steps that must be taken to implement URL rewrite. Can someone take me through the steps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")` will give you the subdomain.

```
if Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")="subdomain.domain.com" then

  response.redirect("http://domain.com/subdomain")

end if
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get URL Rewriting on IIS6 with [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) - it's free. If your web host can install it for you., it's easy to get rewrites on IIS.   If the web host has IIS7 or later, then they can use the URL Rewriting module that's included in IIS7.

Comment: I will ask my host if they can install the module for me. If they don't, then I might have to rely on the custom 404 method. Do you know how to do that?